# Combinatorial argument for why $C(n, k) = C(n, n - k)$?

Tags: combinatorics

> Give a combinatorial argument to show that 
>   $$C(n, k) = C(n, n - k).$$

Any help please?

Comment: This has almost certainly been answered here before, but it’s easier to answer it than to find a duplicate!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Choose $k$ objects from a set of $n$ and remove them from the set; you can just as well view this as having chosen the $n-k$ objects that you left behind.

If you want to be more technical about it, let $\mathscr{K}$ be the set of all $k$-element subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, and let $\mathscr{C}$ be the set of all $(n-k)$-element subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. The map

$$\varphi:\mathscr{K}\to\mathscr{C}:K\mapsto\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus K$$

is a bijection.

**Added:** Suppose that $n=5$ and $k=2$. The table below shows the natural pairing of each $2$-element subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ with its $3$-element complement:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\{1,2\}&\longleftrightarrow&\{3,4,5\}\\
\{1,3\}&\longleftrightarrow&\{2,4,5\}\\
\{1,4\}&\longleftrightarrow&\{2,3,5\}\\
\{1,5\}&\longleftrightarrow&\{2,3,4\}\\
\{2,3\}&\longleftrightarrow&\{1,4,5\}\\
\{2,4\}&\longleftrightarrow&\{1,3,5\}\\
\{2,5\}&\longleftrightarrow&\{1,3,4\}\\
\{3,4\}&\longleftrightarrow&\{1,2,5\}\\
\{3,5\}&\longleftrightarrow&\{1,2,4\}\\
\{4,5\}&\longleftrightarrow&\{1,2,3\}
\end{array}$$

When you choose any of the sets in the lefthand column, you’re implicitly also choosing the complementary set in the righthand column: you’re choosing to leave it behind.

Comment: Could you please give an example so that it would be easier to understand

Comment: @DoctorR : To choose 3 balls in a bag of seven, there is an equal amount of ways to pick the three balls out of the bag or to choose which balls will remain inside the bag. That is, $C(7,3) = C(7,4)$.

Comment: @DoctorR: Done. But I should warn you that you’ll need to learn to construct examples from general descriptions if you’re to get very far with this kind of material.

Comment: @DoctorR: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Here's an easy one. ${n\choose k}$ is the number of subsets of size $k$ from a set of size $n$.  Now look at the unchosen $n-k$ elements.  Each subset of size $k$ generates one subset of size $n-k$. You are done.

Answer (score 4):

An idea: each and every set with $\,k\,$ elements ouf of a set with $\,n\ge k\,$ elements determines uniquely a set with $\,n-k\,$ elements, namely: its complement.

Answer (score 3):

Both are equal to $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ by definition (and the commutativity of multiplication.)

Comment: Oops, I was supposed to make this a _combinatorial_ argument.  How's this: multiplication is commutative because you can count a rectangular array of pennies in two different ways :)

Comment: Lol, nice troll. (The comment I mean.)

Comment: @Patrick Thanks (I think)

Comment: It was a positive comment indeed.

Answer (score 2):

How many ways are there to select $12$ people from a class of $35$ to give a prize to? We **choose** $12$ people, and tell them, you are winners! There are $\binom{35}{12}$ ways to do this.

But alternately, we could **choose** $23$ people from the $35$ and tell them, you are the people chosen not to get a prize. There are $\binom{35}{23}$ ways to do this.  It is clear that there are exactly as many ways to pick the $12$ winners as there are to pick the $23$ losers.

Comment: Thank you. At some editing stage, I changed the numbers, but not enough of the numbers. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can visually see it in Pascal triangle which are the values of $n C_k$ where $k=1 \cdots n$